# Source Engine - What is a "hairball"?

Tags: garrys-mod, source-engine

I was playing around in GMod one day, and I noticed a strange command:
`CreateHairball`
Curious, I tried it out. Strangely, it created several rope-like NPCs that flew away randomly. Killing them crashed the game.
Not only was it in GMod, but Half-Life 2 and Portal had them as well. But what exactly are they, and why are they there?

Comment: Feature of a Weapon designed for HL3

Comment: I've never heard of it.

Comment: @Powerlord In Source Engine games (at least GMod), open the developer's console, type `CreateHairball`, and look near the spawnpoint of your map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Valve didn't explicitly explain why they added it, it feels like a test.

On the [Valve Developer Wiki Page](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CreateHairball), it states:

> This console command creates 100 ropes, each with 3 segments, and simulates them physically while moving them about.

In this text, what you must see is "simulates them physically while moving them about", it *kinda* proves that it was a test.

Also in [a thread](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=971748) in the Facepunch Forums, few users stated that it was a test. Also one said that it might be for liquids (the random moving effect of them, by liquids for example I mean the gels in portal 2, [while they are mid-air](http://www.gamerguides.com/assets/images/library/23/7550-portal2co-opchamber5test6-1png.jpg) ([image source](http://www.gamerguides.com/portal-2/co-op-challenges/course-5-mobility-gels/test-chamber-6-795/)))